# How do I write sound files in python using wave?

Tags: python, wave, winsound

I am trying to make a text-to-sound-file converter with python, it reads the binary data of an input and writes a sound file that matches the data.

1 is a higher note (440 hz) and 0 is a lower note(330 hz). I have tried so many different things and my code is all over the place. Can someone please help me fix it?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import winsound
import wave
import struct
import math
import random
# Parameters
sampleRate = 44100    # samples per second
duration = 1           # sample duration (seconds)
frequency = 440.0       # sound frequency (Hz)
print(os.getcwd())
obj = wave.open('sound.wav','w')
obj.setnchannels(1) # mono
obj.setsampwidth(2)
obj.setframerate(sampleRate)
string=input("Enter text to turn into sound file")
binary=' '.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in string)
print(binary)
for i in binary:
    if i=="1":
        winsound.Beep(440, 500)
        data=struct.pack('<h', 440)
        obj.writeframesraw( data )
    elif i=="0":
        winsound.Beep(330, 500)
        data=struct.pack('<h', 330)
        obj.writeframesraw( data )
obj.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the 'wb' mode when you try to write
(in line 13)

Comment: It's going to take a lot more than that to fix this code.